# Instructions for IIS 7.5 FTP Blind Drop without 500 Errors

Tags: ftp, iis-7.5

I'm trying to setup an IIS 7.5 FTP site with a [Blind Drop](https://web.archive.org/web/20101216022701/http://iisanswers.com/Blind_drop_ftp.htm) box. Directions for 6.0 (Server 2003/XP) don't work as without the list contents permission on the folder itself the FTP server will not allow the user to CD into the directory.

I've found directions [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150116155626/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/vivekkum/archive/2009/05/10/blind-drop-ftp-in-iis-7-7-5.aspx) for setting it up in 7.5, which sort of work. The problem is that when users open the site almost ever client program also lists the directory contents, which returns a server error (either 500 or 550 depending on exactly how it's configured). They see this error and assume the server is not working properly (when in fact it works just fine). Educating all possible users on the inner working of the FTP protocol, and that the error can be ignored, is absolutely not an option.

Has anybody run across a configuration that works like it did in 6.0 (when the user ran `dir` it simply returned nothing in the directory, not an error)?

Comment: As a kludge, I'm interested if putting a file in that directory permissioned so that FTP users can list it, but leave the directory permissions as they are, will cause such clients to not bomb out.

Comment: @sysadmin1138, I've tried a variety of simple fixes like that and it doesn't get around how IIS seems to work. If you deny the user the ability to list folder contents in any way, it relays that denial as an error (which does make sense, but isn't how I need it to work).